# Panda in Python skips computation on first line

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a file with its content as

```
0.08300343840033242
0.5721455830484666
0.46518116038504165
```

I ran following script on it:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
df = pd.read_csv('circle1.csv')
df1 = df**2
print df1
```

Problem in the output is pandas skips the computation on first line but squares the rest of numbers:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Deepak/PycharmProjects/Submission/balnk.py
   0.08300343840033242
0             0.327351
1             0.216394
```

What is causing this trouble and what can be done to resolve it.

Comment: Considers the first line to contain column header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not loading your data properly, it appears your CSV has no headers. In which case, specify `header=None`.

```
df = pd.read_csv('circle1.csv', header=None, names=['Value'])
df

     Value
0  0.083003
1  0.572146
2  0.465181
```

---

```
df ** 2

      Value
0  0.006889
1  0.327351
2  0.216393
```